# Mysql aggregate functions result caching

Tags: mysql

If I have a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  sum(book.numOfPages), sum(book.numOfPages) div 2, 
    sum(book.numOfPages) div 3
FROM
  book
...
```

How many times will mysql actually execute `sum(book.numOfPages)`? Will it cache the first execution and reuse it for later appearance of expression?

Comment: Here is some idea how it works https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html, so many things will be considered before using the cache result. And one major aspect is that whether or not you table data got changed.

Comment: I see, so it's not that simple. Query caching is not even enabled by default...